# Setting environment variable in Python without OS module

Tags: python, environment-variables

I'm using a build of python that doesn't use the OS module because of size constraints, and I'm trying to have it import a module on startup from a directory. From what I understand I can set this using PYTHONPATH, but how would I go about setting that variable without the os module?

Comment: you must start your python with some shell code. you just need to change the env var's there.

Comment: Is there a way to set PYTHONSTARTUP without the OS module? I can set pythonhome and pythonpath just fine but pythonstartup doesn't seem to work.

Comment: you can change all these in shell. but by your description, you seem to be using python in low end embedded system, which i personally think that's the worst idea ever existing in the human history.

Comment: Made a bit of progress, was able to get it to set the variable using export PYTHONSTARTUP=$PYTHONSTARTUP:/path/ but it seems it included : in the path. Now I can't overwrite the value of the variable, it just appends any new values to the end

Comment: you can always overwrite env var by directly assigning. `VAR=10`.

Comment: derp. gotcha. able to set the PYTHONSTARTUP variable to the path I want, but still can't load the module when I boot python, still need to run an export PYTHONPATH=path before I boot python every time. What I'm trying to do is make it skip that step essentially. Just that every time python boots in this environment it already points to that directory for PYTHONPATH. from what I understand this is done using PYTHONSTARTUP correct?

Comment: i don't know what you want. try to put your `export`'s to `/etc/profile`. then reboot.

Comment: You include an enviroment variable for one command in bash by including it right before the command i.e. `X=5 python script.py`

Answer (score 2):

You want  [PYTHONSTARTUP](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONSTARTUP), where you create a startup file and you can import whatever modules you want which will be imported when you start a python shell.

In my home directory I have a file `.startup.py` that looks like the folowing:

```
import datetime, os, pprint, sys, time
print("(modules imported datetime, os, pprint sys, time)")
```

Every time I start a shell the modules are all imported:

```
~$ ipython
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 3.0.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
(imported datetime, os, pprint, re, sys, time)
```

On ubuntu I have `export PYTHONSTARTUP=$HOME/.startup.py` in my `.bashrc`.

I keep a few different modules in a directory called `my_mods`, to add it to my pythonpath I added `export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/my_mods` again in my `.bashrc`.

Comment: This is exactly what I want to do. I'm using busybox however and there is no .bashrc file that I can find. I'm finding an rc file in /etc/ but editing that to include the export command seems to have no effect. Any ideas?

Comment: add a `.sh`  file with the exports  to `/etc/profile.d`, you will need to logout and in to take effect

Comment: No profile.d exists... If I create it will it reference it?

Comment: I am not overly familiar with busybox but I imagine it will work. You can edit `/etc/profile` and add it there but I would recommend trying .d first, there is also `/etc/environment`

Comment: Tried both of those... no luck. Do you know of any way to log what scripts or files are being executed on start up? I'm thinking this thing is using some other file that I'm unaware of as a startup script instead of the typical ones.

Comment: have you logged out and back in  after exporting?

Comment: Yes, completely logged out and back in.

Comment: what does `echo $PYTHONSTARTUP` output? and `echo $PYTHONPATH`

Comment: Nada, no value for either.

Comment: where and how exactly did you try setting them?

Comment: I can set them with an export PYTHONSTARTUP=path, export PYTHONHOME=path and export PYTHONPATH=path manually but I'm trying to get the shell to do that automatically on start up.

Comment: did you try `/etc/environment`? If you want to use `/etc/environment` don't use variable expansion

Comment: I have no experience using busybox but I am amazed none of those work. what shell are you using?

Comment: also do you have a `~/.ashrc` file?

Answer (score 1):

***solution:***

**windows**

```
cmd /c "set app_env=development && python /path/to/python/script.py"
```

**linux**

```
21:14 development [~]% export APP_ENV=development && python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jan 14 2015, 21:37:15) 
[GCC 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> print os.environ.get('APP_ENV');            
development
>>>
```

so that way you can set *PYTHONPATH* as well

Comment: Trying to do this without OS module. I want to set pythonpath in shell, but I'm having to set pythonpath every time I boot up this instance of python. Trying to figure out a way to set pythonpath permanently instead of having to set it every time.

Comment: Are you using linux or windows?

Comment: You can put the export PYTHONPATH=value in /etc/rc.local (available to all users) or your ~/.bashrc (so it's available only for your own logged in user)

Comment: Tried adding export PYTHONPATH=path to /etc/rc and still does not change value on boot of shell. Is there anywhere I can check that this is referencing the correct rc file? If it helps I'm using busybox.

Comment: Are you using docker by any chance?

Comment: Nope, not as far as I know.

Comment: check if your inittab contains the lines for scripts to start and then modify it accordingly

it seems you can modify /etc/init.d/rcS in order to define that sys env var you need