# Launch Python Shell with Predefined Imports and Settings

Tags: python, shell

I am trying to set up a shell-launch script like this:

```
./practice.py
```

I intend to debug commands using various modules which can be tedious to import, set up oauth settings, etc.

How do I set example practice.py to launch with this sort of preset:

```
import module_x
import module_y
from module_z import something

a = something.settings(var_1='123', var_1='456')

>> #start doing stuff
```

Comment: Which OS are you on?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29288382/setting-environment-variable-in-python-without-os-module/29289490#29289490

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`PYTHONSTARTUP`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONSTARTUP) environmental variable. Quoting the documentation:

> `PYTHONSTARTUP`
>
> **If this is the name of a readable file, the Python commands in
>   that file are executed before the first prompt is displayed in
>   interactive mode.** The file is executed in the same namespace where
>   interactive commands are executed so that objects defined or imported
>   in it can be used without qualification in the interactive session.
>   You can also change the prompts `sys.ps1` and `sys.ps2` and the hook
>   `sys.__interactivehook__` in this file.

How you set environmental variables depends on the OS.

Answer (score 1):

Put a shebang at first line with interactive mode switch:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python -i

import module_x
import module_y
from module_z import something

a = something.settings(var_1='123', var_1='456')
```

Then make sure it is executable:

```
chmod +x practice.py
```

Then you can run it like this:

```
./practice.py
```

Answer (score 1):

python (and the more comfortable ipython) support -i somefile.py as option to execute the contents of a file before opening the interactive prompt.

on Linux/Unix/OS X you could simply set that as the interpreter of your script like this

```
#! /usr/bin/python -i
import module_x
# other preloaded settings
```

On Windows you need to create a batch file or similar to wrap it.